# PDO how to insert multiple data to database from an array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi guys after several trials and researching still im not able to do it.

i got this arrays:

```
<td><textarea name="item[]" value=""></textarea></td>
<td><textarea name="description[]" value=""></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty[]" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" /></td>
```

and my methods are here:

```
public function insertRecord($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $args1, $args2, $args3, $args4) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO `request_to_purchase` (`requestedby`, `date`, `jobtitle`, `supervisor`, `notes`) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?)');

    $query->bindValue(1, $param1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(2, $param2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(3, $param3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(4, $param4, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    try {

        $query->execute();

        $lastIDInserted = $this->db->lastInsertId();

        $row = $query->rowCount();

        if(count($row) > 0) {               
            $this->insertItem($lastIDInserted,$args1, $args2, $args3, $args4);
        } else {                
            return false;
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        die($e->getMessage());

    }

}

public function insertItem($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5) {



    $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO `ordered_item` (`rtp_id`, `item`, `description`, `qty`, `amount`, `date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())');

    $query->bindValue(1, $arg1);
    $query->bindValue(2, $arg2);
    $query->bindValue(3, $arg3);
    $query->bindValue(4, $arg4);
    $query->bindValue(5, $arg5);

    try {

        $query->execute();

        $row = $query->rowCount();

        if(count($row) > 0){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;

        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

i used to have four loops that i believe is a wrong practice.

```
for($a = 0; $a < count($item); $a++ ) {

   $test1 = $item[$a];
}

for($b = 0; $b < count($description); $b++ ) {

  $test2 = $description[$b];
}

for($c = 0; $c < count($qty); $c++ ) {

  $test3 = $qty[$c];
}

for($d = 0; $d < count($amount); $d++ ) {

 $test4 = $amount[$d];
}
```

how do i insert those multiple datas on ordered_item table?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that 
`$args1= $_POST['item'],$args2 = $_POST['description'],$args2 = $_POST['qty'],$args2 = $_POST['amount']` are array values then change the following part as below :

```
    if(count($row) > 0) {               
        $argsLen = sizeof($args1);
        for($i=0;$i<$argsLen;$i++){ //loop array and insert
          $this->insertItem($lastIDInserted,$args1[$i], $args2[$i], $args3[$i], $args4[$i]);
        }
    } else {                
        return false;
    }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: hi nouphal!wow! its working!your awesome!but the problem is when insertion happens into the database, i input two values for the four fields so it gave me like item1 descp1 qty1 amount1 and blank item blank desc blank qty blank amount and item2 desc2 qty2 amount2 >>>>as you can see it inserted the two datas but it gave me a blank data, so it inserted 3 datas, item1 blank item and item3

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of the blank insertion after the first value you should change the for loop to increment $i before it checks it against the limit, seems like it's comparing it the first time while $i is still set to 0, so try changing it to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $argsLen; ++$i)
```

Hope this helps.